# Can't set the href on a <link> element using any type of binding

Tags: javascript, css, angular, data-binding, angular-elements

I'm trying to dynamically add a style sheet to an Angular Element. I'm doing this by adding a  to the template. This works fine if I do it through JavaScript. E.g.

```
newLinkElement.setAttribute('href', '//mystyles.css')
```

But if I try to do this with a binding:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" id="backgroundImageStyles" href="{{stylesUrl}}">
```

I get this error
`ERROR in HostResourceResolver: could not resolve {{stylesUrl}}`. If I just change the attribute I'm binding to then the error goes away. E.g. this works:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" id="backgroundImageStyles" lang="{{stylesUrl}}">
```

I've tried `[attr.href]` and `[href]` as well with no luck. Does Angular not allow binding to the href attribute of a link?

Comment: It seems to me you can't implement appending styles to your layout this way. I tried to implement it and this what i got: `HostResourceLoader: loader(StyleFileLink) returned a Promise` I think that's better to control styles via classes then load different files